# PL/SQL CHR(13)||CHR(10) returning 0

Tags: javascript, html, sql, plsql, ascii

I'm using the EMail function in PL/SQL.
The function getting called by Javascript after button got clicked.
This working very fine.

My Problem is that I generate the EMail Body in Javascript using PL/SQL variables.
Code Looks like

```
var content = "Hello " + '|| chr(13)||chr(10)||' + " " + " Name: " + "'||v_name ||'" + '||chr(13)||chr(10) ||' + " ";
```

So here the problem chr(13)||chr(10) returning the character 0 in the string.
But i want a Newline.

I tried with \r\n which didn't worked.
HTML-Tags also don't work because my Email Provider giving me th HTML-Tags out.

Excuse my english :)
Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the '\r\n' in javascript and it worked for me.

`var content = "Hello " + '\r\n' + " " + " Name: " + "'||v_name ||'" + '\r\n' + " Test";
alert(content);`

below is the sample jsfiddle for the same.
https://jsfiddle.net/njbjusmk/.

Comment: Can you post some sample html code with dummy values.

Comment: It's done! The HTML code was very old so the charset were not set on UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure yet, but you might've messed something up with your apostrophes.
Maybe you should try parsing your content as follows:

```
var content = "'Hello '||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||' Name: ||" + v_name + "'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||' " + " Message body "+ "'";
```